# Why is my arrow drawing the wrong way?

Tags: c, opengl-es, 2d, vertices

I have this code to draw an arrow:

```
  const GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.25f,  -0.25f,
      0.0f,    0.0f,
      0.25f, -0.25f,
      0.0f,    0.5f,
  };
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glColor4f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

It **should** draw similar to this:
[image: good arrow]

This is the actual result (which is undesired):
[image: wrong arrow]

I don't see what I have done wrong, the vertices seem correct to me, but it seems like OpenGL draws the polygon in a different order than I specified. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your triangle strip takes the lower three points first (i.e. the lower part of your green arrow) and then the right three points. Just change the order of points in your definition:

```
const GLfloat vertices[] = {
  -0.25f,  -0.25f,
  0.0f,    0.0f,
  0.0f,    0.5f,
  0.25f, -0.25f,
};
```

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why OpenGL uses that order. I'll accept when I am allowed to.

Comment: @Radek S: In general a triangle strip starts with the first three and then removes the first and adds the next and so on. A triangle strip with four points (A,B,C,D) draws the triangles (A,B,C) and (B,C,D).